# Understanding time stamps

Tags: javascript, time, timestamp, momentjs

I have a time stamp that is saved in a db that looks like this
`2022-01-12 11:46:20.660623+00` for new rows in the db I need to add the time in the same format. But Im not sure what the +00 if indicating. Im using moment to create my time stamp so far I have `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ssssss')` but im not sure what the +00 means so Im unsure how to properly add it to the formatting of my new time stamp.
Can someone explain?

Comment: timezone offset

Comment: So like timezone? for example if i did 
`moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ssssssZZ')
'2023-03-23 08:03:33.212121-0500'` this would be equivalent to the example i showed?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 1):

The "+00" indicates the time zone offset from UTC/GMT. So in your case it means that the time stamp is in UTC/GMT time zone.